# Has anyone seen the definition of "alpha function" from Wolfram MathWorld in cited references?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, special-functions

[This](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlphaFunction.html) entry in WolframMathWorld define the "alpha function" as
$$
\begin{aligned} \alpha_{n}(z) & \equiv \int_{1}^{\infty} t^{n} e^{-z t} d t =n ! z^{-(n+1)} e^{-z} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{z^{k}}{k !} \end{aligned}
$$

Unlike other ubiquitous special functions such as beta function and gamma function, I have never seen it in any book I read before. I suspect that if this is simply an entry made up by [Eric Weisstein](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/about/author.html), who is the creator of MathWorld.

Euler certainly had no such notion as this post ([Did Euler have an alpha function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/228543/765539)) on the site shows.  A search on Google does not return anything related to the definition above.

Has anyone seen this definition of "alpha function" in books or journal articles?

Answer (score 2):

The alpha function is a more uncommon name for the [**Generalized Exponential Integral**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/06/01/04/01/01/0003/) which itself is just an [Incomplete Gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/).

Notice that from our bolded link:

$$\text E_v(z)=\Gamma(1-v) z^{v-1}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-k)^n}{(k-v+1)k!}$$

Meanwhile:

$$\alpha_n(z)=n! z^{-n-1}e^{-z} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!} $$

and the [Regularized Gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized/) gives:

$$Q(n+1,z)= \frac{\Gamma(n+1,z)}{\Gamma(n+1)} =e^{-z} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z^k}{k!}, n\in\Bbb N$$

Therefore:

$$\alpha_n(z)=n! z^{-n-1}e^{-z} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}= n!z^{-n-1}\frac{\Gamma(n+1,z)}{n!}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1,z)}{z^{n+1}}$$

is just an elementary function times an Incomplete Gamma function which has [hundreds of papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C39&q=incomplete+gamma+function&oq=incomplete+gamma+) behind it.

We can also use the [following relation](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/27/02/) between the Generalized Exponential Integral function and Incomplete Gamma function:

$$\frac{\Gamma(a,z)}{z^a}=\text E_{1-a}(z)$$

Therefore:

$$\alpha_n(z)=\text E_{-n}(z)$$

so you do not really need the alpha function, just the Incomplete Gamma function or [Genralized Exponential Integral which also has hundreds of papers about it](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C39&q=exponential+integral+function&btnG=) both of which are much more commonly used. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Answer (score 0):

See these:

- [On some properties of the α-Exponential function](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10652469.2012.713359?journalCode=gitr20) Jigen Peng &Jinghuai Gao
- [The k-α-Exponential Function](http://www.m-hikari.com/ijma/ijma-2013/ijma-9-12-2013/ceruttiIJMA9-12-2013-1.pdf) Luciano L. Luque and Ruben A. Cerutti